# How to change the behavior of the file browser

Tags: python, scripting

I was able to call the file browser from Python by referring to a [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42654/ui-how-to-add-a-file-browser-to-a-panel).

I used the following code.

```
import bpy

# Opens a web browser and prints the filepath to console. 
#(To see console.. Window >>> Toggle system console


class OpenBrowser(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "open.browser"
    bl_label = "Minimum code to open browser & get filepath"

    filepath = bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype="FILE_PATH") 
    #somewhere to remember the address of the file


    def execute(self, context):
        display = "filepath= "+self.filepath  
        print(display) #Prints to console  
        #Window>>>Toggle systen console

        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event): # See comments at end  [1]

        context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self) 
        #Open browser, take reference to 'self' 
        #read the path to selected file, 
        #put path in declared string type data structure self.filepath

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}  
        # Tells Blender to hang on for the slow user input


bpy.utils.register_class(OpenBrowser) 
#Tell Blender this exists and should be used


# [1] In this invoke(self, context, event) is being triggered by the below command
#but in your script you create a button or menu item. When it is clicked
# Blender runs   invoke()  automatically.

#execute(self,context) prints self.filepath as proof it works.. I hope.


bpy.ops.open.browser('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

I want to show only folders in the file browser.
But with this code, the user can select both files and folders.

And I don't know how to rename the button in the upper right part of the image.

[image]

If I could specify the first folder to open, I would like to do that too.

Comment: This code is so bad, I really do not understand why the anwer and code you linked to, gets any upvotes at all... and this won't help much in your case. What's your goal? Just selecting a folder?

Comment: Yes.My goal is just selecting folder. I want to allow the user to select a folder to save the files.

Comment: I've tried that code, but it allows me to select `"both files and folders"`. I want to be able to select `"only folders"`. Do you think that's not possible with Blender's Python?

Comment: The code only allows to **select folders** as requested but the **files are visible** as well because that's a *user setting* - click the filter icon in the header, enable *Folders* and the files will disappear, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O30PH.png

Comment: ... and it is possbile to enable that by default *but* then you would have to implement a new operator and this will blow up your code a lot for a tiny little feature. IMHO there should be a good reason to do that.

Comment: Is it equally difficult to specify in code the directory that will be displayed first when the file browser opens?