# Using Python to prompt a user for file selection from a dialog box and append to image strip in VSE

Tags: python, image, video-sequence-editor, file-browser

I am a decently experienced coder and am familiar with Python but am fairly new to Blender and its API. I am able to accomplish my goals manually using the Blender interface but I now must advance to scripting my commands. I have been instructed to create a universal algorithm that prompts the user for file selection from a dialog box, takes those images (given they are the acceptable formats), add them to a single image strip, render the new animation, then use motion tracking on auto-detected points.

I am fairly certain I know how to render and save my file, then the commands to auto detect and motion track points is fairly simple, but this API has been very confusing for me to accept and manipulate user input. I am able to open a dialog box and have the user select files but am unsure where to go from there. I have tried the solution here

[How can i open a file select dialog via python to add an image sequence into VSE?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39854/how-can-i-open-a-file-select-dialog-via-python-to-add-an-image-sequence-into-vse)

but it is from an older version of Blender and complexes my code more than necessary. I also found the Blender Docs on how to open a file dialog box but am unsure how to use the input.

I have rewrote the question more clearly here [Using data from dialog box to create image strip with Python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267712/using-data-from-dialog-box-to-create-image-strip-with-python-script)

Comment: You are right in that the answer to that question is very out of date.  I ran out of time today, but I'll see if I can get you an answer tomorrow, if nobody else has already by then. Do you want help on the dialog box part, how to use the data from the dialog to create an image strip, or both?  If both, please write a second question that can refer to this one, and make one about the dialog and the other about using the results to create the image strip; since stack exchange wants us to limit posts to one question per post.

Comment: @MartyFouts I rewrote my questions here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267712/using-data-from-dialog-box-to-create-image-strip-with-python-script . Apparently there was some issue with a duplicate and I am new to StackExchange so I thought I would just try to reply to you here. If you have a chance to take a look at my problem I would be very grateful, thank you!